# Apache modules mpm-itk and authnz_external

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, authentication, httpmodule

I want to use to in one VirtualHost authnz_external module for system users and mpm-itk module for running it under another user. My config file for VirtualHost look similar as this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
AddExternalAuth pwauth /usr/bin/pwauth
SetExternalAuthMethod pwauth pipe

<IfModule mpm_itk_module>
AssignUserId user1 apache
</IfModule>

<Directory /var/www/user1_folder/>
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/user1_folder/apache.users
AuthName "private area"
AuthBasicProvider external
AuthExternal pwauth
require valid-user
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But if I use this configuration, I'm not able to login to web. In the Apache error_log file is this:

```
[Wed Jun 14 15:43:04.449652 2017] [unixd:alert] [pid 17150] (1)Operation not permitted: AH02156: setgid: unable to set group id to Group 0
[Wed Jun 14 15:43:12.027069 2017] [authnz_external:error] [pid 17149] [client 83.158.44.101:59772] AuthExtern pwauth [/usr/bin/pwauth]: Failed (1) for user user1
[Wed Jun 14 15:43:12.027108 2017] [auth_basic:error] [pid 17149] [client 83.158.44.101:59772] AH01617: user user1: authentication failure for "/user1_folder": Password Mismatch
```

If I disable mpm-itk module or authnz_external module all works fine.

CentOS 7.3,
httpd 2.4.6,
mod_authnz_external 3.3.1,
pwauth 2.3.10,
httpd-itk 2.4.7.04